# Which culture first referenced bigfoot?

Tags: folklore

Bigfoot and Sasquatch have a lot of tales and history in different regions.  What was the first point of reference for these stories/sightings.

Also to make this a little clearer.  Can we just throw out giants which tend to have biblical/spiritual/religious linkage?  I am specifically asking for the big hairy guy that walks around in the woods/mountains.

Comment: In Nepal? In interior British Columbia? Please refine your question to be answerable rather than merely a request for a list.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Wondering how far back the legends/folklore go.  Not really looking for a list or a specific region.

Comment: afaik the first references to bigfoot are from the mid-20th century. Certainly the first (invariable manufactured) "evidence" is from that era.

Comment: When Ugh looked over at Grog while huddling around the fire and they both looked out at the 'noise of footsteps'...

Answer (score 1):

If you include references to sasquatch by first nations in the pacific northwest then they back far further than mid 20th century. I cant tell you when the first reference was but sasquatch has been part of first nations mythology for at least hundreds of years. In some BC museums (Vancouver Museum at the planetarium) there are masks depicting sasquatch that are hundreds of years old.

Answer (score -1):

Cave art from 8,000 B.C. along the Clumbia River shows that the Mooly Gooly people were the first ones to waste their time fretting about the preposterous myth of Bigfoot.